# No me cargan los anuncios intersticiales

Tags: android, android-studio

La verdad no sé cómo explicar bien bien lo que me sucede.

En mi app, al momento de probarla, no muestra ningún anuncio, ni el 'BANNER' que tengo al fondo de la pantalla ni los intersticiales.

Pensé que era cosa mía y aún así lo publiqué. Ya publicado vi que sí salen los anuncios en el 'BANNER' de abajo, pero los intersticiales no.

He hecho de todo, he cambiado el código de los anuncios para mostrar los de prueba, y nada.

Me sale lo siguiente:

> I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
mAdView = context.findViewById(view);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    if (tipo != 0) {
        Log.i("ANUNCION", "ENTRA EN EL ANUNCIO 2");

        InterstitialAd.load(context,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/8691691433", adRequest,
                new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                        // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                        // an ad is loaded.
                        mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                        Log.i("ANUNCION3", "onAdLoaded");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error
                        Log.i("ANUNCION3", loadAdError.getMessage());
                        mInterstitialAd = null;
                    }
                });

        if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
            mInterstitialAd.show(context);
            Log.i("ANUNCION", "si entra aquí es porque lo debe estar mostrando");
        } else {
            Log.i("ANUNCION", "si entra aquí es porque el OBJETO ES NULL");
        }
```

Ahora, explicando un poco mi código. Tengo una clase aparte con el código mostrado anteriormente. Allí cargo el anuncio del banner con el pedazo antes del primer 'if'.

Dicho 'if' es para que la primera pantalla no muestre un anuncio intersticial.

Cuando el usuario hace cambio de pantalla, entonces le mando que el tipo es 1, lo que hace que entre en ese primer 'if' para mostrar un anuncio intersticial.

Luego, en la parte de abajo llamo al método show() para que muestre el anuncio intersticial, pero no lo hace, ni siendo un anuncio de prueba, ni con la app publicada en la Play Store.

Ya he hecho de todo pero con esta nueva implementación no me sale. Anteriormente mi app mostraba dichos anuncios sin ningún problema, incluso hasta los de prueba.

Gracias de antemano.

Añado esto:

Veo que me salen mensajes como estos:

```
I/com.vungle.warren.AdLoader: didn't find cached adv for AdRequest{placementId='MREC1-3356020', adMarkup=null, type=0, adCount=1} downloading
D/com.vungle.warren.AdLoader: No adv for placement MREC1-3356020 getting new data
V/com.vungle.warren.AdLoader: [ttDownloadContext] Start to request ad, request = AdRequest{placementId='MREC1-3356020', adMarkup=null, type=0, adCount=1}, at: 1643231482865
V/com.vungle.warren.AdLoader: [ttDownloadContext] Request ad got response, request = AdRequest{placementId='MREC1-3356020', adMarkup=null, type=0, adCount=1}, elapsed time = 680ms
D/com.vungle.warren.AdLoader: Ads Response: {"ads":[{"placement_reference_id":"MREC1-3356020","ad_markup":{"id":"","campaign":null,"app_id":null,"sleep":1685,"info":"impression auctioned but unsold","delay":0,"showClose":0,"showCloseIncentivized":0,"countdown":0,"url":"","videoWidth":0,"videoHeight":0,"requires_sideloading":false}}]}
```

Tienen algo que ver con mi problema?
Llevo varios días así, y nada que me sale ni 1 anuncio intersticial.

```
D/TAG: The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.
2022-01-26 16:55:51.604 8183-9328/layco.suerteloteria W/Ads: Not retrying to fetch app settings
```

Esto también:

```
W/OkHttpClient: A connection to https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/ was leaked. Did you forget to close a response body?
```

Comment: Mi app sigue sin mostrar ningún anuncio intersticial. Dudo que sea que no tengan inventario para ello, ya que mi otra app (la cual no le he cambiado la implementación aún) sigue mostrando estos anuncios...

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a el error que obtienes

> I/Ads: Ad failed to load : 3

Si revisas la [documentaciòn](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL), el id del error especifica

[ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest#ERROR_CODE_NO_FILL)
La solicitud de anuncio se realizó correctamente, pero **no se devolvió ningún anuncio debido a la falta de inventario de anuncios**.

El código de error sugiere que la implementación es correcta, **no hay problemas en el còdigo pero la solicitud de anuncio no obtuvo respuesta debido a la falta de disponibilidad de un anuncio adecuado en ese momento en particular** cuando se envió una solicitud de anuncio desde la aplicación.

> **Por qué sucede?**: los anunciantes pueden dirigirse a regiones,
> plataformas y perfiles de usuario específicos en función de la
> relevancia comercial, lo que a veces puede resultar en una menor
> disponibilidad de anuncios para una región o perfil de usuario en
> particular.

Comment: Gracias por responder, pero ni siquiera me salen los de prueba, que es lo más raro de todo. Lo otro es que tengo varios días con la app en el Store en su versión actualizada y nunca me ha salido un anuncio intersticial, cuando antes esto nunca me pasaba.

Comment: Si en los Anuncios de prueba obtienes "Ad failed to load : 3" es lo mismo no siempre se tiene un anuncio para devolver cada solicitud, esto puede suceder si acabas de registrar tu id anuncio ya que  se necesita algo de tiempo para que se comiencen a mostrar anuncios.

Comment: No, ya tengo como 5 años, mínimo, con el ID y con los mismos bloques de anuncios creados.